# How to get a float array from a List of 3 doubles?

Tags: c#, linq

having a class that holds 3 double values x,y,z

```
 public struct Point : IEquatable<Point>, IComparable<Point>
 {
        public double _X;
        public double _Y;
        public double _Z;
        public double X { get { return _X; } set { _X = value; } }
        public double Y { get { return _Y; } set { _Y = value; } }
        public double Z { get { return _Z; } set { _Z= value; } }
        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            _X = x;
            _Y = y;
            _Z = 0;
        }
        public Point(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            _X = x;
            _Y = y;
            _Z = z;
        }
}
```

Inside a loop I fill a List of points like

```
   AllDataPoints = new Point[100];
   double x,y,z;
   for (int i = 0; i < SOMESOURCE.values; i++)
   {
        x = SOMESOURCE.X;
        y = SOMESOURCE.Y;
        z = SOMESOURCE.value;
        AllDataPoints[i] = new Point(x, y, z);
    }
```

Then I want to put in one float array all z values.

How can I accomplish this with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inside a loop I fill a List of points

You can do it without a loop, like this:

```
arrayResult = SOMESOURCE
    .Select(item => new Point(item.X, item.Y, item.value))
    .ToArray();
```

> I want to put in one float array all z values.

LINQ's `Select` lets you do this:

```
var allZs = arrayResult.Select(pt => (float)pt.Z).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a float result with LINQ :

```
float [] arrayResult = AllDataPoints.Select(e => (float) e.Z).ToArray() ;
```

or if you want to stay with double values :

```
double [] arrayResult = AllDataPoints.Select(e => e.Z).ToArray() ;
```